# Mysql selecting with sum() and group by from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, group-by

TABLE 1

```
---------------------------------------
| id | item | MU | quantity | file_id |
---------------------------------------
| 1  |item1 | oz | 3.5      | 003     |
| 2  |item2 | kg | 1.1      | 001     |
| 3  |item1 | oz | 0.2      | 001     |
| 3  |item1 | kg | 3        | 001     |
```

TABLE 2

```
 ----------------------------
 | id | date      | file_id |
 ----------------------------
 | 1  |timestamp1 | 001 |
 | 2  |timestamp2 | 002     |
 | 3  |timestamp3 | 003     |
```

What i'm trying to do is to select the sum of quantity for each group of items that have the same MU. I manage to do that with this query.

```
$query = "SELECT item,SUM(quantity) from table1 GROUP BY item,mu";

with a great result, exactly what i wanted
----------------------------------
| id | item | MU | SUM(quantity) |
----------------------------------
| 1  |item1 | oz | 3.7           |
| 2  |item2 | kg | 1.1           |
| 3  |item1 | kg | 3             |
```

But now, how do i get **only** the rows that their file_id date is BETWEEN two timestamps ?

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY on each of these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage to achieve this using [**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) and joining the two tables in a single query, simply replace `initialdate` and `finaldate` with your current timestamp

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.item, a.mu, SUM(a.quantity) as total_quantity from table1 a left join table2 b ON a.file_id = b.file_id WHERE b.date BETWEEN initialdate AND finaldate GROUP BY a.item,a.mu";
```

Comment: great, i knew that i should read more about mysql JOIN :D, it's not very clear in my head :) , thanks

Comment: so if i want from all these returned by your query just those items (from table 1) that their id is present in a third table?

Comment: @user348078 i would suggest to post a new question with your code and the problem you find in compiling it

Comment: there is no need to post a new question. the simpliest answer with the followup question by the OP is to use `INNER JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`. just as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

You can join both table using `INNER JOIN`. The result of the query will only show `items` from `Table1` which matches between the two dates, otherwise it is not included in the result list.

```
SELECT  MIN(a.iD) ID, a.item, a.MU,
        SUM(a.quantity) totalQuantity
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.file_ID = b.file_ID 
WHERE   b.date BETWEEN startDateHere AND endDateHere 
GROUP   BY a.item, a.MU
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: i think you want this. Use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: one more thing, `MIN(a.iD) ID` is optional.